# Widows10 ページングファイル設定の異常

Tags: windows-10

## 状況

DriverHubというソフトウェアを使用し、ドライバーを更新後、PC起動時に以下のメッセージダイアログが出るようになった。

```
[システムのプロパティ]
コンピューターの開始時にページングファイル構成に問題が発生したため、一時ページングファイルが作成されました。全ディスクドライブの総ページングファイルサイズが指定したサイズよりも大きくなっている可能性があります。
```

PCにOSを再インストール（出荷設定）をしても、ダイアログが表示されます。

システムのプロパティをOK通すと、パフォーマンスオプションダイアログが開かれ、仮想メモリの変更を行っても、再起動後には設定が反映されず、同じダイアログが表示されます。

## 試したこと

- 工場出荷設定によるOS再インストール
- 以下のサイトに書かれていること。

[PC起動時に、ページングファイルに関するエラーが出ます。](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/forum/all/pc%E3%81%AE%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB/d6372e86-5074-48f9-833a-9833471f513b)

- sfc /scannow
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
- 不要一時ファイルの削除
- ！および？マークのあるデバイスマネージャでの削除

## 知りたいこと

このダイアログ表示が出ないように修復したい。

Comment: 実メモリサイズやDISKの構成・サイズ・空き領域、そしてページングファイル設定ダイアログ上の各数値などの具体的な値を示した方が良いと思われます。[仮想メモリの設定が反映されない](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/forum/all/%E4%BB%AE%E6%83%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A2%E3%83%AA/2a10ddb8-b8b2-4792-a1d2-cfc038743d10), [ページングファイル構成に問題が発生のエラーを解消](https://www.losttechnology.jp/blog/2019/01/%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E6%A7%8B%E6%88%90%E3%81%AB%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E3%81%8C%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92/), [仮想メモリについて質問があります。](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11219421626)

Comment: 個人のブログのようですが、こういう情報もあるようです(https://fireflyframer.blog.jp/19064532.html) 更新したドライバが実際のハードウエアに合っておらず、機器が損傷している可能性も考慮されてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど、不適切なドライバというのが当てはまりそうです。ヘルスチェックしても、リカバリしても直せないというのは、困りました。

Answer (score -1):

リカバリしてもエラーが出るってのは、ハードウエアのトラブルです。
まずは、HDD／SSDを交換してみよう

＃それでもダメなら、メモリ異常あるいはPC本体の異常